# How do I book a family carriage on VR Finnish trains from Helsinki to Turku?

Tags: trains, bookings, family, finland

I couldn't find my way around their website

[image]

I am not even sure if this a coach you can book exclusively for your family or it's a play area on the train but it's a great way to travel with children, I first found about it on [this page](http://familyinfinland.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/finnish-train-travel-with-kids.html)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each playroom coach have 4 regular seats that can be reserved, no surcharge applies.  Just book your ticket normally at the [VR Shop](https://shop.vr.fi/), making sure to select one of the trains equipped with a playroom of course.  Look for the little teddy bear icon next to Services:

[image]

Then "continue to seat selection", and request a seat "Next to Playroom":

[image]

Note that you don't *have* to book a seat in that section if you want to use the playroom, and for your sanity you might not want to!  All kids are welcome to use it.